# Can i publish 80 port with public IP?

Tags: apache, ip, firewall, public

i can access my Apache server by 80 port from my LAN.
i disabled my firewall(80 only) for incoming and outgoing.
can i publish my 80 port using my public ip on internet?

Comment: What do you mean with "publish" ?

Comment: access my public_html by web browser over internet

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your setup. I assume you have a router at home which your computer/server is connected to. You'll have to forward the port in your router configuration to your computers port.

You can find more information [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html) about forwarding ports.